Dimension Compatibility in Fisher Information Matrix for Gaussian Mixture Models
I'm working on deriving the Fisher Information Matrix (FIM) for a two-component bivariate Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM). I've encountered a question about dimension compatibility in one of the terms, and I'd appreciate some clarification.
Context:
Consider a two-component bivariate GMM with the following parameters:

$\pi = [\pi_1]$ (mixing coefficient, $1 \times 1$ scalar, $\pi_2 = 1 - \pi_1$)
$\mu = [\mu_1, \mu_2]$, where $\mu_i = [\mu_{i1}, \mu_{i2}]^T$ (mean vectors, each $2 \times 1$)
$\Sigma = [\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2]$, where $\Sigma_i = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{i1}^2 & \sigma_{i12} \\ \sigma_{i12} & \sigma_{i2}^2 \end{bmatrix}$ (covariance matrices, each $2 \times 2$)

The GMM probability density function is:
$f(x; \theta) = \pi_1 f_1(x; \mu_1, \Sigma_1) + (1-\pi_1) f_2(x; \mu_2, \Sigma_2)$
Where $f_i(x; \mu_i, \Sigma_i)$ is the bivariate normal density function:
$f_i(x; \mu_i, \Sigma_i) = \frac{1}{2\pi|\Sigma_i|^{1/2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu_i)^T\Sigma_i^{-1}(x-\mu_i)\right)$
The log-likelihood function is:
$L(\pi, \mu, \Sigma) = \log(\pi_1 f_1(x; \mu_1, \Sigma_1) + (1-\pi_1) f_2(x; \mu_2, \Sigma_2))$
Problem:
I'm trying to compute the Fisher Information Matrix using the formula:
$I_{ab} = E\left[\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial a}\right)\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial b}\right)^T\right]$
Specifically, I'm looking at the term $I_{\mu\Sigma}$, which has the form:
$I_{\mu_i\Sigma_j} = E\left[\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu_i}\right)\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \Sigma_j}\right)^T\right]$
Here's where I'm confused:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu_i}$ is a $2 \times 1$ vector
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \Sigma_j}$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix

Question:
How is the multiplication $\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu_i}\right)\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \Sigma_j}\right)^T$ compatible given these dimensions? What is the correct way to interpret and compute this term in the Fisher Information Matrix?
Additional Information:

The partial derivatives are:
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu_i} = \gamma_i(x)\Sigma_i^{-1}(x - \mu_i)$  ($2 \times 1$ vector)
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \Sigma_j} = \frac{1}{2}\gamma_j(x)[\Sigma_j^{-1}(x-\mu_j)(x-\mu_j)^T\Sigma_j^{-1} - \Sigma_j^{-1}]$  ($2 \times 2$ matrix)
Where $\gamma_i(x)$ is the responsibility of the i-th component.

I would greatly appreciate any insights on how to correctly compute this term while maintaining dimensional consistency. Thank you!

I'd go with $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\text{vec}(\Sigma_j)}$.

I was also thinking the same, but my question will it be still align with the standard formula?

The formula applies to vector-valued parameters. For matrix-valued parameters, the Fisher information will not be a "matrix" (2D array), but will be a higher-dimensional array.
